# Drag and Drop visual editor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drag-and-drop, antlr

In my current project, I write high-level specification ( as indicated below for reference) and am parsing it using grammar written in ANTLR and then using StringTempate to generate equivalent Java programming code.  Now, my client finds the writing of this textual high-level specification difficult and want me to provide equivalent visual drag and drop programming constructs and editor to specify this programming constructs. My question is : **does eclipse provide any
drag and drop workbench to develop visual programming constructs and editors?**
It MAY be easy to integrate with ANTLR.

A Sample example or its link will be useful.

```
TemperatureSensor
      generate tempMeasurement : TempStruct;

TempStruct
      tempValue : double;
      unitOfMeasurement: String;
```

Comment: You might want to look at [Eclipse XText](http://eclipse.org/Xtext/)

Comment: Thanks greg for the reply ! But, Isn't xText for the development of textual editor?

Comment: One of the claims on the home page is 'Xtext provides a rich API to work with resources. Therefore developing additional graphical and structural views is comparably easy. '

Comment: Do we have a small hello world example if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at Graphiti, it is much lighter than GMF and easier to setup.
https://eclipse.org/graphiti/

In any case to leverage existing tools in eclipse to manipulate models, you absolutely need a metamodel to integrate into the EMF, so you might use Xtext to develop that, based on your existing antlr grammar.

Comment: Graphiti has been in incubation forever, and seems to have taken a back seat to Sirius. At the EclipseCon in San Francisco earlier this year, no one was talking about Graphiti, but Sirius had a big presence. This is, in part, due to the difference between the approaches taken by these two tools. Graphiti, in short, requires you to write a lot of code, whereas Sirius is primarily declarative.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Eclipse Graphical Editing Framework (GEF)](https://eclipse.org/gef/), it's a framework for creating graphical editors in an Eclipse-based product or plug-in. There are even some efforts to integration GEF with [XText](http://eclipse.org/Xtext/), for example [this one](https://github.com/spoenemann/xtext-gef).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Eclipse has the Sirius project. https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/